# Docker authentication using keycloak based on namespace

Tags: docker, keycloak

I have integrated keycloak to docker for authentication but am not able to find weather there is a way to give separate groups in keycloak for different namespaces in docker.

Comment: Do you mean this with 'docker for authentication'? https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/31/docker-authentication-keycloak/

Comment: Yes for docker registry authentication